# Converting an ArrayList to separate arguments for a varargs constructor

Tags: java, oop, constructor, ellipsis

I'm not sure if what I want to do is feasible, but I'll explain the reasoning up front and then what I'm trying to do.

I'm using a framework for evolutionary computation that is essentially generating a tree structure from the constructor I'll be describing, where each node can have a variable amount of child nodes.

I'm trying to code up a generic node constructor that accepts a variable amount of parameters, which serve as the child objects to that node (so a node can have from 1 to  children based on this ellipsis).

If I were to do this by hand for 2 children, I'd have a function like the following, where `super` is calling the parent class which creates the overall structure for the current node:

```
public Wrapper(final SageProgram sp, final Node child1, final Node child2) {
        super(child1, child2);
}
```

However, as I mentioned, I'd like to extend this, so I'm attempting the following:

```
public NWrapper(final ArrayList<Node> children) {
        super(children.toArray(new Node[children.size()]));
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting a `java.lang.ArrayStoreException`, as the variables in the constructor turn out to be array types (`Node[]`) instead of the singular type (`Node`).

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Please provide the exact exception and stack trace, and mark the line that throws the exception.  Is it the `super` call? Is it thrown in the super constructor? Somewhere else?

Comment: Its a fairly complicated framework so I abstracted it down to this problem.  It is an ArrayStoreException as indicated, basically is trying to set a `Node` variable to a `Node[]`.  The issue as I understand it, is that by passing the array to the super constructor, I'm effectively passing it `Node[]` instead of separate Node variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps instead of:

```
    public NWrapper(final ArrayList<Node> children)
```

You can break the objects into `Node[]` objects and `Node` objects.  Then process them inside your wrapper.  The shell would then be something like the following:

```
    public NWrapper(final ArrayList<Node[]> children_lists, final ArrayList<Node> children)
```

You will still have to handle your call to your super class as needed.